# Do system admin can change database admin?

Tags: sql-server

I have requested my system administrator to install sql server 2008 r2 in my system

During the installation the system admin added myDomain\MyUsername as a use of the database.

But he has given me only “public” server role to myDomain\MyUsername .

So I am not able to create a database.

He also don’t know what password he given for “sa” user during installation.

At present I don’t have admin access in my machine (operating system:windows7).

My question is

“if I have admin right on my opearating system, will 'myDomain\MyUsername' have full privileges on the sql server?”

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236.aspx *Starting SQL Server in single-user mode enables any member of the computer's local Administrators group to connect to the instance of SQL Server as a member of the sysadmin fixed server role*

Comment: Really came in handy once or twice :)